# How to play .flv files in windows phone 7 or windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I find apps in marketplace to play flash files but i need the way how to play flash file

Comment: [Player Framework for Windows 8 and Windows Phone](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.windowsphone.com/ru-ru/store/app/yxplayer-wp8/dd50db36-7dab-4696-acb4-2f2184cc1dbb
How about this app, but unfortunately it's not trial